# Why apply sum by column and colSums differs when dataframe contains date format?

Tags: r, date, sum, apply, lubridate

In the example bellow, why A is not equal to B ? The problem is related to the Date column since AA=BB, but I can't understand why...

```
library(lubridate)
MM=data.frame(ID=1:3,Date=ymd(c("2019-11-07","2019-11-07","2019-11-13")),X=c(-1,1,1),Y=c(1,-1,-1))
A=apply(MM,2,function(x) sum(x>0))
B=colSums(MM>0)
A
# ID Date    X    Y
# 3    3    0    0 
B
# ID Date    X    Y 
# 3    3    2    1
AA=apply(MM[,-2],2,function(x) sum(x>0))
BB=colSums(MM[,-2]>0)
AA
# ID  X  Y 
# 3  2  1 
BB
# ID  X  Y 
# 3  2  1
```

R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `apply`, before applying the function to each column, first of all converts the data.frame into a matrix.

Therefore:

```
> as.matrix(MM)

     ID  Date         X    Y   
[1,] "1" "2019-11-07" "-1" " 1"
[2,] "2" "2019-11-07" " 1" "-1"
[3,] "3" "2019-11-13" " 1" "-1"
```

Everything is converted to character.

Specifically, you can see that:

```
> " 1" > 0
[1] FALSE
> "1" > 0
[1] TRUE
```

This is because 0 is converted to char.

"0" comes before " 1" alphabetically because the character 0 gets compared to the blank instead of the character "1".

The order of strings are decided by comparing character by character 1 by 1.
(it's the same reason why `"10" > "9"` is `FALSE`, because `1` alphabetically is before `9`).

```
> sort(c("0", " 1"))
[1] " 1" "0" 
> sort(c("0", "1"))
[1] "0" "1"
```

As a consequence:

```
> as.matrix(MM)>0
       ID Date     X     Y
[1,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

`colSums` doesn't do that.

---

You can get the same result you would get with `colSums` if you do:

```
> apply(MM>0, 2, sum)
  ID Date    X    Y 
   3    3    2    1
```

Comment: In contrast, `MM > 0` works with the integer values underlying a `Date` object.

Comment: `sapply` doesn't do this either, so `sapply(MM, function(x) sum(x>0))` works as intended.

Comment: And everything is coerced to a character matrix (not "date time").

Comment: Ok ! Thanks ! But, what is tested in `as.matrix(MM)[1] > 0` ? Why `"1">0`returns TRUE and `" 1">0` doesn't ?